# oracle parameter enable_shared_pool_durations setting to true or false

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aix, oracle11gr2

Could ANYONE please help ME to identify if this change of parameter could affect the operation of the application?
Oracle 11gR2 DB.

alter system set "_enable_shared_pool_durations"=false scope=spfile sid=*

Can this parameter affect or produce the new error for DB too?

Comment: Exactly what dot release of Oracle are you using, and who is recommending that you use this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a setting that is used as a workaround for a small number of unpublished bugs around shared pools and ASMM.

It seems to be something you should only do if directed to by Oracle Support.

From MOS:

`_enable_shared_pool_durations=false`

This affects the architecture of memory in the pools.

When _enable_shared_pool_durations is FALSE, subpools within the SGA will no longer have 4 durations.

Instead, each subpool will have only a single duration.

This mimics the behavior in 9i, and the shared pool will no longer be able to shrink.

The advantage of this is that the performance issues such as **sudden drop/resize/shrink of buffer cache (Doc ID 1344228.1)** can be avoided.

A duration will not encounter memory exhaustion while another duration has free memory.

The **disadvantage** is that the shared pool (and streams pool) are not able to shrink, mostly negating the benefits of ASMM.

PLEASE NOTE : Even if you have AMM / ASMM disabled similar behavior might be seen as per the note.